# Como definir caminho .bat

Tags: windows, batch

Bem meu problema é o seguinte eu quero rodar um arquivo .bat que vai:

- criar uma pasta localmente
- copiar imagens do meu servidor para a pasta criada
- esconder a pasta criada

Porém ele acaba exibindo essa mensagem :

```
C:\Wallpaper especifica um nome de arquivo
ou de diretório no destino 
(F = arquivo, D = diretório)?
```

Como eu faço pra definir C:\Wallpaper como Diretório

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
XCOPY /E "[caminho do servidor]" "C:\Wallpaper"
attrib +h "C:\Wallpaper"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acabei entrando no "Explorador de arquivos" e olhando como ele define pastas e reparei que ele põe uma "\" no fim quando é uma pasta ...

Então só tive que colocar uma **backslash** na primeira linha:

```
XCOPY /EY "[caminho do servidor]" "C:\Wallpaper\"
attrib +h "C:\Wallpaper"
```